# How to set Google Maps Home address accurately?

Tags: google-maps

My home is in a remote location and as Google Maps doesn't have street-specific database for my location, I can't write my address like (House No, Street, Society, etc). I can only set my home to my society and the home on Google maps is around 200 metres away from my actual home (center of the housing society).

Is there a way I can set my home address accurately (e.g. through coordinates)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, is possible to set the home and work locations using coordinates. In Google Maps app go to menu -> settings -> edit home or work -> edit home address. Now enter the coordinates in the search box and it will be saved.
I am inclined to think that this will work, because I tried with random coordinates corresponding to a spot in the sea and Maps let me use them. If it doesn't, consider sending a request to [Add a missing place](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6320846?hl=en&ref_topic=3311561), which you can do from inside the app as follows:

- Search for an address.
- At the bottom, touch the address.
- Touch Add a missing place.

Note, though that:

> Adding places using Google Maps isn't available everywhere, but you might be able to use [Google Map Maker](https://www.google.com/mapmaker) to add places that matter to you.